# ANTLR using a symbol as a token name

Tags: token, antlr, lexical-analysis

I want to use `(` as a token name in a ANTLR lexer file.  I've tried several versions, but none of them seem to work and cause errors when building.  Here are my (broken) attempts:

(1) `(: '(';`

(2) `'(': '(';`

(3) `'\(': '(';`

(4) `\(: '(';`

Is this possible and, if so, how would I do that?

Comment: Is it necessary? Probably not. (1) You can use the string literal in the parser rules in your grammar. NB: in a split grammar, you can use the string literal as long as you have a lexer rule with the string literal on the RHS; in a combined grammar, you probably don't even need to define a lexer rule for the string literal. So, you can write in the parser grammar, "a: '(' foobar ')';" (2) For a tree walker, test the token text. Otherwise, you will likely have to declare the token type to coordinate with the tree walker. This is because Antlr will declare a generated token symbol name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. A rule name must start with an underscore or letter, and is followed by zero or more underscores, letters or digits. So `'('`, or whatever variation of it, is not a valid rule name.